# Microsoft Identity Platform: what happens when refresh token expires?

Tags: microsoft-identity-platform

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens#refresh-token-lifetime) documentation that says that the refresh token will expire in 24 hours for single page applications, but I don't understand if making a refresh token call to the apis retrieves a new refresh token that I can still use or instead I have to prompt the user to login again (I don't  fully understand what the blue box says).

[image]

> Additional refresh tokens acquired using the initial refresh token carry over that expiration time, so apps must be prepared to rerun the authorization code flow using an interactive authentication to get a new refresh token every 24 hours

Does this mean the user must insert credentials again?

> Users don't have to enter their credentials and usually don't even see any related user experience, just a reload of your application

It looks like he doesn't have to.

> The browser must visit the log-in page in a top-level frame to show the login session

But this part looks like has to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/966440/msal-token-expires-after-a-day) link that answers my questions

> Refresh tokens given to Single-Page Applications are limited-time refresh tokens (usually 24 hours from the time of retrieval). This is a non-adjustable, non-sliding window, lifetime. Whenever a refresh token is used to renew an access token, a new refresh token is fetched with the renewed access token. This new refresh token will have a lifetime equal to the remaining lifetime of the original refresh token. Once a refresh token has expired, a new authorization code flow must be initiated to retrieve an authorization code and trade it for a new set of tokens.

Note: When a new refresh token is obtained, msal.js replaces the cached refresh token with the new refresh token, however the old refresh token is not invalidated by the server and may still be used to obtain access tokens until its expiration.